# Check which anonymous function a var is in Scala

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

I have a scenario where I have an anonymous function stored in a var

```
val x = Integer.max _
```

and I want to do some logic like

```
if(x == Integer.max _){
    println("Using the max function")
}
```

But I've noticed that these anonymous functions never equal each other.

```
val x = Integer.max _
val y = Integer.max _

println(x==y)   //false 
println(x eq y) //false
```

So is there anyway I can check what anonymous function I have; and if I can't what's the best way to mimic this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT there is no clean way of doing this. The problem is that Scala compiles all anonymous functions into anonymous classes - so different anonymous functions get different classes (hence why `==` indicates they are different).

```
scala> val x: (Int, Int) => Int = Integer.max
x: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> x.getClass
res: Class[_ <: (Int, Int) => Int] = class $anonfun$1
```

The simple solution is to make a variable for the anonymous function you will use. For example,

```
val max: (Int, Int) => Int = Integer.max
...
val x = max
...
if (x == max) {
    println("Using the max function")
}
```

Otherwise, you might try verifying that the anonymous classes for both functions are structurally identical, but that might turn out to be pretty unpleasant.

Comment: Thank you, this will work for my purposes.  Though it would be nice if scala compiled the same function into the same class each time.